# Allow use special commands on input validating

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a little problem with validating an input field.

Here is my validation code:

```
    _validateInput: function(e) {
        var value = e.currentTarget.value;
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        var re = /[^0-9\.]/gi;
        if (re.test(value + String.fromCharCode(key))) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return value + String.fromCharCode(key);
        }
    },
```

The logic is the next. If user input non-digital characters, the function return current value of the input, without the last symbol.

If user type digit or dot, function return current input value + entered number.

**What is my problem:**

1) It not allows user to enter dot.

2) String.fromCharCode for dot character returns "¾" symbol.

3) Special symbols like backspace, tab, etc... doesn`t work.

4) Commands like Ctrl+V, Ctrl+A also does not work

Could someone help me to solve this problems? What is wrong with my RegEx? 
Thanks!

P.S. Function fired on the keydown event

Comment: Use `oninput` instead of `onkeyup/down/press` and forget `String.fromCharCode()`, just play with the value.

Comment: I don't understand your regex. Mind explaining me the `\.` ? It is finding characters which are not between `0` and `9.` ? Sorry for my ignorance, I am new to regex expressions

Comment: @Teemu But, on oninput event (or just input event in Backbone), the user first see what he entered. And I want first validate user`s input, and then entered  this validated value as a value for the input.

Comment: @pablito.aven. This regEx must block all non digital and dot symbols

Comment: `oninput` is the only reliable event for this, it takes care of all possible chages, including clipboard actions, dropping a value etc. Notice, that you're not getting "charCode" from `onkeyup/down`, that will be a mapped key code. `onkeypress` gives you a "charCode", you can use that, but compare numbers to numbers, there's a swamp ahead if you're trying to convert codes back to characters. Modern browsers have also [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), which gives you the real _character_ entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need to support older browsers listen for `oninput` instead of `onkeydown` and a lot of the processing will have been done for you.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

> This event is similar to the onchange event. The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed. The other difference is that the onchange event also works on <keygen> and <select> elements.

Whenever `oninput` is triggered then check the value in the text area is valid and if it isn't then correct it. This will also let you check for multiple dots being entered (if you need to do that). For example `231.21.23` is not a valid number.

Comment: Thanks! Input event is realy nice :)